# ? in Doctrine query means?

Tags: doctrine

i wonder what this query means:

```
$blogPost = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('BlogPost p')->where('p.slug = ?', 'doctrine-released')->execute();
```

could someone explain the ? for me?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing, but I would bet money that the `?` is just a way of saying 'there is a variable here and I will later populate it', just like normal binding in other SQL varieties.  In your example, that would imply that the `?` is expanded to 'doctrine-released' at execute time.  In other words, the query becomes `where p.slug = 'doctrine-released'`

Comment: but why not just write p.slug = 'doctrine-released'. what is the benefit with this?

Comment: Because you can use the advantages of prepared statements. Check this : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: In this exact example, it seems like it might not be worthwhile to use a prepared statement.  But when your database has thousands of users, and they all use the exact same prepared statement but execute it with different bind variables, you will save yourself a ton of parse-time and memory.

Comment: The parameter that you bind to the prepared statement is also escaped thus making your code more secure.

Comment: Doctrine caches its DQL queries, and regardless of being not so noticeable on small-scale implementations it's still worthwhile using prepared statements (since it's so easy) as by doing this it can tell when a query is the same as another with just an attribute value changed- and therefore re-use / optimise etc.

Comment: As Goran points out, the variable will be escaped. If it's an integer, you can write it p.slug = 1 and the query will work fine.

Comment: Just to be clear -- I was not saying don't use prepared statements.  I was saying it might 'seem' unnecessary, but you should do it.  So I agree with all y'all.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a variable as the parameter then the '?' is used other wise '?' is not needed.

For example:

$blogPost = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('BlogPost p')->where('p.slug = ?', $doctrine-released)->execute();

and in case of a string as a param

$blogPost = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('BlogPost p')->where('p.slug' = 'doctrine-released')->execute();